# List iterators incompatible and Arithmetic overflow

Tags: c++, iterator, runtime-error

I have such part of the code:

```
for (auto i = 0; i < WINDOW_SIZE; ++i) {
    if (current == goal) break;
    if (came_from.find(current) == came_from.end())
      break;
    next_best = came_from[current]; 
    if (space_map[i].find(next_best) != space_map[i + 1].end()) {
      auto search1 = space_map[i].find(current);
... ... ... ... ... ...
```

Where

```
1) space_map: std::vector<std::unordered_map<Node, Agent*>> (where Node and Agent are my onw classes.)
2) came_from: std::unordered_map<Node, Node>
3) current, goal: Node
4) WINDOW_SIZE: define, which equal 8
```

There is listing of hash_map specialization for the unordered_map, and Node:

```
namespace std {
template <>
struct hash<Node> {
  std::size_t operator()(const Node &n) const {
    std::size_t const h1 = std::hash<std::size_t>{}(n.x);
    std::size_t const h2 = std::hash<std::size_t>{}(n.y);
    return (h1 ^ (h2 << 1));
  }
};

}  // namespace std
```

```
typedef struct Node {
  uint x, y, f_score, g_score;

  bool operator==(const Node &n) const { return (x == n.x && y == n.y); }

  bool operator!=(const Node &n) const { return (x != n.x || y != n.y); }

  friend std::ostream &operator<<(std::ostream &out, const Node &n) {
    out << '[' << n.x << ", " << n.y << ']';
    return (out);
  }
} Node;
```

When I'm starting the Debuging, I receive such error:
[image: error's image]

I considered the case with WINDOW_SIZE - 1, probably it was an overflow error. But not sill the same error.
I figgured out that an error occurs here:

```
if (space_map[i].find(next_best) != space_map[i + 1].end())
```

Also I have such notification, that I have a "C26451: Arithmetic overflow" with "+" here `space_map[i + 1].end()` [i + 1]. Probably it will helpful.
Could someone explain me, where am I wrong?

Comment: You cannot compare iterators from different containers (well, it compiles, but it's never going to return any reasonable results). Not sure what the standard says about such attempt, probably an Undefined Behaviour.

Comment: Is `space_map[i + 1].end()` a typo for `space_map[i].end()`? If not, what is it supposed to be doing?

Comment: Please give a [mcve]. Missing all kind of stuff here. And did you notice "press retry tip debug the application"? You can debug it.

Comment: Off-topic -- 1) `typedef struct Node` -- No need for `typedef struct` in a C++ application - just use `struct Node`.   2) `bool operator!=(const Node &n) const` -- No need to manually rewrite `==` and turn it inside-out.  Just `return !(*this == n);`

Comment: The Microsoft compiler, in a Debug build, includes lots of extra checking.  One of the things it checks is that both iterators used in a comparison come from the same container.  This assertion failure is the results when they do not.  `space_map[i]` and `space_map[i+1]` are different containers and are the cause of your error..

Comment: @uneven_mark no. I need exactly i + 1. I woud like to check if the next 'Node' which is best for me is exsist.

Comment: How about dropping `i` and using iterators, too prevent the mistake uneven_mark mentioned... listen to the people here `space_map[i].find(next_best) != space_map[i + 1].end()` is bad,  m'kay?

Comment: @JHBonarius Nope I can't

Comment: Ok, if you are convinced that you are right, then we're cannot help you. Good luck with the "alternative facts"

Comment: @JuiceFV If be shortly, I tried to implement the algorithm wich solve Coopirative Pathfinding problem, and I shall to find the best node. In this part of the code I just check does the next node exist.

Comment: @JuiceFV *I just check does the next node exist* -- and if it doesn't exist, what gets returned?  That answers your question as to what you're doing wrong.

Comment: @JHBonarius No< I'ill try

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You didn't give a Minimal, complete verifiable example

But `space_map[i].find(next_best) != space_map[i + 1].end()`

Is not possible. [`std::unordered_map::find()`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/unordered_map/find) returns an iterator. And:

> ## Return value
>
> Iterator to an element with key equivalent to key. *If no such element is found, past-the-end (see `end()`) iterator is returned.*

But the iterator of `space_map[i]` **is different from that of `space_map[i+1]`**. You cannot compare two different iterators

So it either should be

```
space_map[i].find(next_best) != space_map[i].end()
```

or

```
space_map[i+1].find(next_best) != space_map[i+1].end()
```

You don't show enough code, so I have to make assumptions here. I would use a a local reference, to prevent making this mistake.

```
for (auto spMpCurrent = std::cbegin(space_map);
     spMpCurrent != std::next(std::cbegin(space_map), WINDOW_SIZE);
     spMpCurrent++) {
    if (current == goal) break;
    if (came_from.find(current) == came_from.end()) break;
    next_best = came_from[current]; // inline this?
    auto spMpNext = std::next(spMpCurrent);
    if (spMpNext->find(next_best) != spMpNext->end()) {
      auto search1 = spMpCurrent->find(current);
```

Your design looks very (unnecessarily?) complex. Maybe it can be simplified... but as you don't show enough code, we cannot help you